# Word vectors as input

Tags: deep-learning, keras, word-embeddings, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

I have a corpus on which I want to perform sentiment analysis using LSTM and word embeddings. I have converted the words in the documents to word vectors using Word2Vec. My question is how to input these word vectors as input to Keras? I don't want to use the embeddings provided by Keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just skip the Embedding layer and use a normal input layer with **n** input nodes where **n** is the dimensions of your word2vec embeddings. The rest is the same as you would with an embedding layer, just pass a sequence of **n** dimensional vectors as the input, potentially padded or truncated depending on your model.

Answer (score 1):

Keras does not provide pre-trained word embeddings out of the box.  Do you need to avoid using the Embedding layer entirely?  If not, you can use that layer as an input for a matrix of pre-trained word vectors.  You can load in your pre-trained embeddings as the initial layer weights using the `weights` property of the layer.  If you set `trainable=False` then your word embeddings will not shift when you run your model.

Here's a snippet of code from an [example using pre-trained word vectors](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py#L116) from the Keras Github repo:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(nb_words + 1,
                        EMBEDDING_DIM,
                        weights=[embedding_matrix],
                        input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                        trainable=False)
```

If you do need to avoid the Embedding layer entirely, then @Jan's probably gives you what you need.